# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'org.json.JSONArray org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(java.lang.String)

Tags: android, ip

i have 2 class with this same error, can you tell me what is wrong with it, i used local ip adrees. it is 10.0.2.2
here is my doInBackgroundclass

```
String url_param;
        url_param = "http://10.0.2.2/webservice/android.php?pl=info";

        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url + url_param);
        Log.d("log", "url:" + url + url_param);
        try {
            JSONArray result = json.getJSONArray("result");
            for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject c = result.getJSONObject(i);
                String id = c.getString("id");
                String nama = c.getString("nama");
                String info = c.getString("info");
                String tanggal = c.getString("tanggal");

                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                map.put(in_id, id);
                map.put(in_nama, nama);
                map.put(in_info, info);
                map.put(in_tanggal, tanggal);
                resultList.add(map);
            }
            Log.d("log", "bla:" + resultList);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
```

here is the log cat, so at first i thought it's from ip address but i'm not sure, i put this server on localhost

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
                                                                     java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
                                                                         at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                                                                         at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                                         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                                                                      Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'org.json.JSONArray org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url + url_param); Make sure that json is not null after this line.

Comment: okay thank you, now it's work. it's because the code you gave me and i change the url param

Comment: glad to help ;)